# HDMI to VGA converter, no image from Banana Pi

Tags: linux, debian, hdmi, vga, arm

I'm trying to use a [Banana Pi](http://www.lemaker.org/resources/9-166/banana_pi.html) with Bananian OS (Debian 7 based) on a monitor that does not have a HDMI input but a VGA. So I bought a HDMI to VGA adapter. I followed the instructions written [here](http://linux-sunxi.org/Fex_Guide#disp_init_configuration) to enable the VGA output on Allwinner SoC editing the `script.bin` (after the conversion to fex file) in the `disp_init` configuration section:

`script.fex`:

```
[disp_init]
disp_init_enable = 1
disp_mode = 0
screen0_output_type = 4
screen0_output_mode = 5
screen1_output_type = 2
screen1_output_mode = 11
fb0_framebuffer_num = 2
fb0_format = 10
fb0_pixel_sequence = 0
fb0_scaler_mode_enable = 1
fb1_framebuffer_num = 2
fb1_format = 10
```

and editing also the `uEnv.txt` boot configuration file

`uEnv.txt`:

```
bootargs=console=ttyS0,115200 console=tty0 disp.screen0_output_mode=800x600p60 console=tty1 root=/dev/mmcblk0p2 rootfstype=ext4 elevator=deadline rootwait
aload_script=fatload mmc 0 0x43000000 script.bin;
aload_kernel=fatload mmc 0 0x48000000 uImage; bootm 0x48000000;
uenvcmd=run aload_script aload_kernel
```

I get no signal to the Monitor. I tested the converter with my HDMI-out notebook port and it works ok with that (on the same monitor). Any suggestions?

Comment: I don't know.. but this is for the rpi https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=91&t=24504&p=474076#p474076     the banana may be very different though.  For the rpi try the numbers on the keyboard 1,2,3,4 https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/setting-up-raspbian-and-doom   after turning it on..  don't know if that will work on the banana, but for the rpi one of those was HDMI one was another video output etc.

Comment: also i don't know whether it's for hdmi to vga, or for vga to hdmi, but it may need to be powered. Is your adaptor powered?

Comment: @barlop the adapter is not powered. The problem is that RPi is not a *"sunxi"* device. The most similar device to Bpi is the CubieBoard, but I also crawled in those forums finding nothing.
I'm starting to think it's a power-related issue (even if on the converter Amazon page the buyers are saying that they can use it with the RPi)

Comment: As a test, you could try your adaptor and monitor  in a regular computer's hdmi port

Comment: @barlop I did this. The converter works ok!

Comment: maybe the converter works ok, but i'm no expert and maybe the computer provides more power to hdmi than the banana does to hdmi. so maybe a powered adaptor is more important when dealing with the banana, that's just a weak theory, I have no idea, but I am just saying I wouldn't be so quick to conclude that the adaptor is ok.

Comment: @barlop I think It could be a power issue. I'll buy a powered converter and see if it works.

Comment: Instead of a 800x600 resolution, you should try using the resolutions that are common to HDMI and VGA and video, which are 1280x720 and 640x480 (or 720x480), and are guaranteed to not require any scaling or interlacing (which most low-cost converters cannot do).